# Resetting loop counter

Tags: ruby

How do I change the code below so that when "BYE" is shouted in all caps three times in a row, it exits the code? (Counter resets to `0` otherwise). The code is supposed to exit from all caps from any word, so BYE would have to be an exclusion to this rule.

```
puts "say something to grandma"
number = rand(1900..2015)

while true
  talking = gets.chomp
  talking.downcase

  puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"

  if talking == talking.upcase
    puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{number + (1)}!"
    break
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much described the solution in your question: Add a condition that checks if the user typed `BYE`. If they did, add one to the counter. If the counter is 3, `break`; otherwise go to the top of the loop with `next`. If they didn't type `BYE`, reset the counter to 0.

```
puts "say something to grandma"
number = rand(1900..2015)
counter = 0

while true
  talking = gets.chomp

  puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"

  if talking == "BYE"
    counter += 1
    puts "You said 'BYE' #{counter} time(s)"
    break if counter >= 3
    next
  end

  counter = 0

  if talking == talking.upcase
    puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{number + 1}!"
    break
  end
end
```

A few notes:

1. You'll notice that I removed `talking.downcase`. It wasn't doing anything. I suspect you meant to use `downcase!`, which modifies the string (whereas `downcase` returns a new string, which you weren't doing anything with), but that would have broken the code (because the condition would never be true).
2. Instead of `while true`, `loop do` is somewhat more idiomatic in Ruby.
3. You may want to test whether the user entered anything, since `"" == "".upcase` is `true`.

Comment: Ah. Unfortunate, that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any counter in your code.
If you want to exit the loop when "BYE" is repeated `3` times in a row, you would need to have a counter for that. So I added the variable `counter` that will start from `0`, and will reset to `0` each time, a word other than "BYE" is called.
It will break from the loop if it reaches `3` or if the user wrote other uppercase word, like in your original script.

```
puts "say something to grandma"
number = rand(1900..2015)
counter = 0

while true
    talking = gets.chomp
    talking.downcase

    puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
    if talking == "BYE"
        counter += 1
    elsif talking == talking.upcase
        counter = 0
        puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{number + (1)}!"
        break
    else
        counter = 0
    end
    if counter == 3
        break
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it obvious how the counter works, perhaps you could use an array `counter` that gets filled with a `'BYE'` every time the user answers `'BYE'`. If the user answers anything *other than* `'BYE'` the `counter` is reset to `[]`. Essentially three `'BYE'`'s in-a-row is represented by the array `counter = ['BYE', 'BYE', 'BYE']`.

The code could be something like this:

```
counter =  []
while counter != ['BYE', 'BYE', 'BYE']
  puts "You're in a room with Deaf Grandma. Say something to her"
  a = gets.chomp

  if a == 'BYE'
    counter << 'BYE'
  elsif a == a.upcase
    r = rand(21) + 1930 
    puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + r.to_s + '!'
    counter = []
  else
    puts 'HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
    counter = []
  end

end
```

Notice this line from the code above:

```
while counter != ['BYE', 'BYE', 'BYE']
```

This ensures the while-loop keeps running *while* the `counter` array is **NOT** equal to `['BYE', 'BYE', 'BYE']`. So if `counter` equals `[]` or `['BYE']` or `['BYE', 'BYE']`, the while-loop keeps running. It only stops when `counter = ['BYE', 'BYE', 'BYE']`.